# How to resolve a promise when the calling method is not asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

**I'm having the same issue with RXJS**

I'm using angular-auth-oidc-client. To load several configurations, I'm using this factory.

```
const httpLoaderFactory = (configService: CustomConfigService) => {
  return new StsConfigHttpLoader(configService.getConfigs$())
}

@NgModule({
  imports:[
    AuthModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: StsConfigLoader,
            useFactory: httpLoaderFactory,
            deps: CustomConfigService
        }
    })
],
//...
})
export class AuthConfigModule{}
```

This is how the service looks like.

```
export class CustomConfigService{

getConfigs$(): Observable<OpenIdConfiguration>[] {
    //make call to the backend 
    //generate OpenIdConfiguration object for each client
    //return an array of Observable<OpenIdConfiguration>
  }
 }
```

To request the list of clients from the backend, I will need to use **observable** or **promise**.

The problem is that when I can't use the await keyword without decorating the method with the async keyword as well.

```
getConfigs$(): Observable<OpenIdConfiguration>[] {
    return await somePromise(); /// needs to decorate the method with async
}
```

The problem with that is the initial calling method is complaining about the type being `Promise<T>` instead of `T`, in this case `Observable<OpenIdConfiguration>[]`.

Using then promise won't work

```
getConfigs$(): Observable<OpenIdConfiguration>[] {
  let result;
  somePromise()
    .then((r) => result = r);

    return result; //this will run before the promise resolves...!!!!!
}
```

I'm really stuck. Is there a workaround on this situation?

Thanks for helping

## EDIT

```
return this._store.pipe(
  select(mySelector), //request data
  map((data) => this.transformToConfig(data)
);
```

if I return this as it is, it will be an `Observable<Observable<OpenIdConfiguration>[]>`. The calling method expects a T, i.e. an array of observables.

Comment: Async functions always returns a promise.  What's the problem with changing the return type to Promise<yourType>?

Comment: Look at the code I posted. The `factory` is not an async function. If I try to decorate it with the `async` keyword, then I get an error. However, without async, I can't use `await` either to resolve the value. So I'm stuck.

Comment: To convert a promise to an observable, use the `from` function in rxjs. `getConfigs$(): Observable<OpenIdConfiguration>[] { return from(somePromise()); }`

Comment: Converting the promise to an observable won't help either as I will end up with `Observable<Observable<OpenIdConfiguration>[]>` instead of `Promise<Observable<OpenIdConfiguration>[]>`. The library is expecting an array of observable like this `Observable<OpenIdConfiguration>[]`

Comment: @NicholasTower, plus take a look at the edit.

Comment: @Richard77 That is an observable for an array of configurations, not an array of observables.

Comment: @Richard77 You can easily flatten two nested observables. Or just use `flatMap` instead of `map` in the first place.